# Can this code be written in a more functional style

Tags: functional-style, coding-style

Referencing [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3789/8), I wonder if the following code can be written more concisely using a functional style, i.e. without `For` loops or `ReplacePart`?

```
Parti[A_, p_] := Module[{An, i = 1, j = 1}, 
 An = Drop[A, Flatten[Position[A, p]]]; 
 For [j = 1, j <= Length[An], j++, 
  If[An[[j]] < p, 
  An = ReplacePart[An, {j -> An[[i]], i -> An[[j]]}]; i++]; ]; 
  Insert[An, p, i] ];
```

Where

```
A1 = {3, 5, 6, 2, 1}; 
Parti[A1, First[A1]]
```

has the expected output: `{2,1,3,5,6}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two more ways:

```
   parti1[a_, p_] := SortBy[a, {Sign[# - p] &, # == # &}]
```

or

```
   parti2[a_, p_] := Join[Select[a, # < p &], {p}, Select[a, # >= p &]]
```

With

```
  a = {3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1, 2}; (* and *) p =3
```

both give

```
  {2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7}
```

**Update:** While the two methods above and Heike's two methods give exactly the same results, unfortunately, it turns out that `Parti` is a tougher nut than it seemed at first glance and none of these functions replicate `Parti` except for very special inputs. Here is why:

These functions, in effect, partition a list into lower and upper contour sets of the element `p` preserving the original ordering of the elements in each subset. With `Parti`, on the other hand, the orginial ordering is preserved only for the lower contour set, and the ordering of the elements in the upper contour set is not preserved. That is, when an element in the lower contour set moves it moves to the right of his previous left sibling and stays there, while an element on the upper contour set can move many times during the operation of `Parti` depending on the pattern of elements on its right.

For example, for the input list `{3, 2, 5, 6, 2, 1}` all four functions agree with `Parti`, i.e.,

```
 Parti[{3, 2, 5, 6, 2, 1}, 3]==parti1[[{3, 2, 5, 6, 2, 1}, 3]=={2, 2, 1, 3, 5, 6}
```

Yet, with a slight change in the list to `{3, 2, 5, 2, 6, 1}`, we get

```
  Parti[{3, 2, 5, 2, 6, 1}, 3] (* => {2, 2, 1, 3, 6, 5} *)
```

while `parti1` and its siblings give

```
  parti1[{3, 2, 5, 2, 6, 1}, 3] (* => {2, 2, 1, 3, 5, 6} *)
```

Another example: for the input list `{3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1}`

```
   Parti[{3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1},5]   (* =>  {3, 2, 2, 1, 5, 8, 9, 6, 7}, but *)
   parti1[{3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1},5]  (* =>  {3, 2, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}      *)
```

Thus, the elements of the upper contour set always move to the right but their final positions relative to each other cannot be determined in a simple manner without using finer pattern information.

So ... it seems that the `parties` are interesting, at best, as a first step towards an answer to OP's question, and, quite possibly, as just answers seeking an interesting question.

**A new attempt: Try `ReplaceRepeated` and pattern matching:**

```
  partiReplace[a_List, p_] := 
  With[{leftlist = Alternatives[Sequence @@ Select[a, # < p &]], 
  rightlist =  Alternatives[ Sequence @@ Select[a, # >= p &]]}, 
  (Drop[a, Flatten[Position[a, p]]] 
  //. {Shortest[beg___], i : rightlist, 
  Shortest[rgtn : rightlist ...], 
  j : leftlist, k : leftlist ..., end___} 
  -> {beg, j, rgtn, i, k, end}) 
  // Insert[#, p, 1 + Length@(leftlist)] &]
```

**Tests:** For the examples considered above, `partiReplace` gives the same result as `Parti`.

For a limited set of test data

```
  testdata = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {100, 21}];
```

we get

```
   Parti[Most@#, Last@#] == partiReplace[Most@#, Last@#] & @@ testdata 
   (* => True  *)
```

Comment: why does this construct `{Sign[# - p] &, True &}` work?

Answer (score 7):

One way of doing this is to do something like

```
parti[lst_, p_] := Flatten[Reap[Sow[#, Sign[# - p]] & /@ lst, {-1, 0, 1}][[2]]]
```

If the list consists of integers only, you could also do something like

```
parti[lst_, p_] := Flatten[BinLists[lst, {{-Infinity, p, p+1, Infinity}}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution that takes advantage of the `Sign` function, but exploits the fact that `Sign` is listable so we only have to call it once, and then uses the wonderful [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pick.html) function to extract the three lists before joining them back together.

```
Pillsy`Parti[A_, p_] :=
 With[{signs = Sign[A - p]},
  Join @@ (Pick[A, signs, #] & /@ {-1, 0, 1})];
```